# How to dynamically update div to add embedded tweet followed by other HTML elements

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a chatbox inside which I dynamically add content. This content includes text from p tags. I want to embed tweets inside the chatbox div. I was able to get this part to work using twitter widget. Problem is when I append anything to the message div after the embedded tweet, the tweet vanishes.

I tried both append and innerHTML ways of appending content to div.

This is the code I used to add content to message div:

```
var div = document.getElementById('messages_window');
div.innerHTML += '<p> <b>'+query+'</p>'; // for adding text to div
div.innerHTML += response // response contains the embed code for the tweet
```

Currently, appending content to the message div works in below scenarios:

1. I keep adding p tags one after the other and they all show up as expected
2. I add several p tags and then append the embed code of a tweet and the tweet shows up in the div as expected

Problem is when I have appended the embed code and follow it with any other data, the data gets appended but the tweet is lost. I used the below code to load the twitter widget

```
(document).ready(function() { 
 twttr.widgets.load(document.getElementById("messages_window"));  
   });
```

Any help's appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the entire contents of `messages_window` using `innerHTML`.

You should use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead to append as many elements as you want.

```
var div = document.getElementById('messages_window');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p><strong>' + query + '</strong></p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', response);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried insertAdjacentHTML but it's still not retaining the tweet. I also noticed that the problem is when I call ```twttr.widgets.load(document.getElementById("messages_window")); ```. If I skip this, then the tweet loses all the styling but the further content gets appended without the tweet being lost.